# Limitando execução de eventos e escutando eventos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso limitar o numero de vezes que um botão é clicado, abaixo o codigo do mesmo

```
    $(".add-produtos").on("click", function(){
    for(var z = 0; z < 17; z++) {
        var testar = produtoObj(i++); //produtoObj é o objeto que renderiza os proddutos na tela, se for necessario posta-lo me falem.
        testar.renderiza();
    };
});
```

E também queria saber como faço para ao carregar mais produtos eles tenham atrelados a eles a função abaixo

```
        function addCarrinho(){
        var total = 0;

        $("#circulo").html(total);

        $(".material-icons").on("click",function(){
            var soma = total++;
            console.log(soma);
            var somado = soma.toString();
            console.log(somado);
            $("#circulo").html(total);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor? `1-` _"limitar o numero de vezes que um botão é clicado"_ é para evitar cliques demasiado rápidos ou há um limite máximo de cliques que depende de outra variável? `2-` Acho que queres usar delegação, ou seja mudar para `$(document).on("click", ".material-icons", function(){` mas seria interessante ver mais código para ter a certeza. Por exemplo: de onde vem `total`?

Comment: `1-` é para que só seja possivel chamar a função uma vez.<br>
Para que possas ver melhor o código, estou mandando o link do repositório no github https://github.com/victorhcosta/get-devs